# .value not working in for forms javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms, output

When I use the form element I get an error saying that it can't set the properties to `undefined`.

html:

```html
<form name="regForm">
    <table>
        <tr> <!-- First Name -->
            <td>
                <input id="firstName" type="text" placeholder="First Name">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr> <!-- Error Box -->
            <td>
                <p id="returnOutput"></p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr> <!-- Submit button -->
            <td>
                <button type="button" onclick="validateForm()">Sign Up</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Javascript:

```js
function validateForm() {
    var firstName = regForm.firstName.value;
    
    regForm.returnOutput.value = firstName;
}
```

This is for an assessment so it needs to be done this way otherwise I would be using `document.getElementById().value`

Comment: You can't rely on names and ids of the elements to create a global variable. Use a DOM getter like [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) to get references to the elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

regForm is undefined; you need to define it first.

Just a tip: use const for values that won't change, it's good practise!

```
function validateForm() {
    // SELECT regForm by it's name. It doesn't have an ID, so we have to select it by name. However, if it did have an ID, we can use it. 0 is just to select the first element it finds since getElementsByName returns a node list
    const regForm = document.getElementsByName("regForm")[0]
    // Declare firstName as the firstname.value
    const firstName = regForm.firstName.value;
    // Finally, append it to body :)
    document.getElementById("returnOutput").innerHTML = firstName;
}
```

Comment: It works thanks. what does the `[0]` do at the end of the first `const`?

Comment: @DTracey read the comment just above it.. getElementsByName returns a 
node list (https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_nodelist.asp), and the 0 selects the first element in the node list